# how to set desecending order in datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I am trying to set default sort to datatable but its not working,below i have given code which i am working.I want to set sort to desecending order to lastupdate column,I used "order"":[1,desc]. but this is not working.

//below is my jquery

```
   $('#tableId').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: {
            "url": "{{route('data.get')}}"
        },
        columns: [
            {data: 'name', name: 'name', ordarable: true, title: 'Name'}, 
            {data: 'updated', name: 'updated', ordarable: true, title: 'Last Updated'} 
        ]
    });
```

//below is my table in html

```
      <table id="tableId" class="display table table_legenda" style="width:100%">
      </table>
```

Comment: The syntax is: `"order": [ [ 1, "desc" ] ]`

Comment: You should try to explain what you mean by "not working", since the syntax shown to you by @Michel and by @BernhardBeatus is [correct](https://datatables.net/reference/option/order). One way to explain is to provide a [mre] which shows us exactly _how_ you are using their suggestions, and allows us to run the exact same code that you are using. You can, for example create a CodePen or Fiddle to show us your code. (Also, bear in mind that you are using `ordarable` - which is not a valid option.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#example').DataTable({
     dom: 'Bfrtip',
     "paging": true,
     "order": [
       [1, "desc"]
     ],
     columnDefs: [{
       orderable: false,
       targets: 0
     }],
     columns: [{
         data: 'name',
       },
       {
         data: 'surname'
       },
       {
         data: 'position'
       },
       {
         data: 'office'
       },
       {
         data: 'salary'
       }
     ],
     buttons: [{
       extend: 'excelHtml5',
       exportOptions: {
         orthogonal: 'export'
       }
     }]
   });
 });
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.24/js/jquery.dataTables.js" async></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>First name</th>
                <th>Last name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger</td>
                <td>Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>
       <select>
                <option value="">Select Report</option>
                <option value="test">tests</option>
                <option value="test">121212</option>
      
      </select></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Garrett</td>
                <td>Winters</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
               <td>
      test123</td>
              <td>
       <select>
                <option value="">Select Report</option>
                <option value="test">tests</option>
                <option value="test">121212</option>
      
      </select></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ashton</td>
                <td>Cox</td>
                <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
              <td>
       <select>
                <option value="">Select Report</option>
                <option value="test">tests</option>
                <option value="test">121212</option>
      
      </select></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cedric</td>
                <td>Kelly</td>
                <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
               <td>
       <select>
                <option value="">Select Report</option>
                <option value="test">tests</option>
                <option value="test">121212</option>
      
      </select></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Airi</td>
                <td>Satou</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
              <td>
       <select>
                <option value="">Select Report</option>
                <option value="test">tests</option>
                <option value="test">121212</option>
      
      </select></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Brielle</td>
                <td>Williamson</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>New York</td>
               <td>
       <select>
                <option value="">Select Report</option>
                <option value="test">retrww</option>
                <option value="test">121212</option>
       <option value="test">btersdf</option>
      </select></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Herrod</td>
                <td>Chandler</td>
                <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>
       <select>
                <option value="">Select Report</option>
                <option value="test">tests</option>
                <option value="test">121212</option>
                  <option value="test345">test1234</option>
      
      </select></td>
            </tr>
          
        </tbody>
    </table>
```